# What is the canonical design pattern/construct in iOS when a model should start some activity shortly after starting?

Tags: ios

The high level design of my app consists of the App Delegate being the owner of the model which is created in didFinishLaunchingWithOption and then the app delegate passes a reference to the model to any controller class that needs to use it.

On app launch my app needs to call home to a server and download some content. This must be something common done by many apps, my question is what is the standard way of doing so, in particular which object and at at what point should be responsible for instructing the model to connect to the server? Lets assume there is a function on the model called CallHome() implemented asynchronously using NSURLConnection which can notify interested classes when complete.

Where should I perform this:

1) Could it be done in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

2) If didFinishLaunchingWithOptions should execute and return before the model executes CallHome() then which class should call CallHome()? Can the AppDelegate do this? If so where?

3) Could the model invoke CallHome() itself, if so when?

4) Or is this actually the job of a controller? If so should it be the root controller?

5) However what if the root controller doesn't need a reference to the model otherwise? So does that imply it should be another controller?

What is the recommended approach for the high level design for this functional requirement?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make any server requests not before first view controller's `viewDidAppear` you can trigger your web service request in `viewDidAppear` of first view controller.
the reason behind the scene is if you web service call is `synchronous`, it will block the `main thread` (your application ideally, should not block application's main thread) and hence on device your application will crash unexpectedly during launch and hence will be rejected by apple on submitting it for AppStore.

Comment: I'm using NSURLConnection asynchronously, and the model has a protocol defined so user's can be informed when its finished downloading the content. So does this affect the answer? Could the model start the downloading in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and a controller gets notified when its finished. Or should it still not even start the process until viewDidAppear?

Comment: thats what is mentioned in my answer, you should not block the main thread with synchronous call. for all asynchronous transactions, there is no issue calling them from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in short - you already have done the correct implementation..